# Time series decomposition in R

Tags: r, time-series

I've recently started dabbling with some time-series analysis in R, and I'm a little confused as to how the filter function in the stats library works. Essentially, I've seen it asserted that, for a daily time series, that filter could be used to decompose the series into yearly, seasonal and weekly components using something like the following:

```
x.year <- filter(x, rep(1/365, 365))
x.season <- filter(x, rep(1/90, 90))
x.weekly <- filter(x, rep(1/7, 7))
```

While I can figure out that the rep(1/period, period) gives you a component of length period, I'm not sure *why*, and am trying to avoid cargo cult analysis. Consulting the documentation, that bit is apparently, "a vector of filter coefficients in reverse time order" - just not sure what that means.

Anyone care to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you first look at what a [Convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) is. When you understand it well, you should easily see that using `filter` to compute the convolution of your signal `x` with `rep(1/period, period)` is nothing more than computing the "moving average" or "rolling mean" of your signal, see for yourself:

```
x <- runif(10)
filter(x, rep(1/5, 5))
# Time Series:
# Start = 1 
# End = 10 
# Frequency = 1 
#  [1]        NA        NA 0.4400744 0.3643682 0.2677056 0.3703566 0.3449967
#  [8] 0.4975061        NA        NA

library(zoo)
rollmean(x, 5, na.pad = TRUE)
#  [1]        NA        NA 0.4400744 0.3643682 0.2677056 0.3703566 0.3449967
#  [8] 0.4975061        NA        NA
```